# bootstrap modal issue in chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, twitter-bootstrap, model-view-controller, modal-dialog

I have a bootstrap modal in my asp.net mvc code that it's body bind in runtime.
first time I click on the some button and modal work good (body return from controller by jquery ajax).

then must change model’s body dynamically , it works good too(by jquery Ajax and json). then I close modal.
second time I click on some button , modal work but with problem .
the problem is scrollbar of modal's body is enable but not working , like that the modal is lock .
this problem is in chrome , but in IE I have not that.
my code for modal :

```
...
success: function (response) {
$('#myModal').html(response);
$('#myModal').modal({ show: true, backdrop: false, keyboard: false });
...
```

I change css : `overflow:hidden` and `position:fix` but it's not work

Answer (score -4, accepted):

the only suggestion is click F12 in chrome and try to debug. but my initial guess is that some  CSS standard is diff with two explorer.

Comment: This doesn't really provide an answer to the question, it only suggests an approach that might be used to debug. This kind of response would be better suited for a comment on the original post.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem. I found the solution, but I don't know How It Works.
The solution is, add some jquery codes I wrote below.

```
  $('.modal').bind('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    $(".modal").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
  });
  $('.modal').bind('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    $(".modal").css("overflow-y", "auto");
  });
```

Good Luck!