# Twitter Bootstrap modal background not staying fixed

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal for a yelp place search. Once I do a yelp search for places, the original model's height is extended and is populated with the returned data. However, when I scroll, the background does not remain fixed.

I noticed bootstrap adds a style height property in the modal backdrop and that does not adjust size unless the page is refreshed or when I open the console in chrome and then close it.

```
<div class="modal-backdrop fade in" style="height: 1344px;"></div>
```

This is my html code that I am currently using:

```
 <div class="page-container">
 <div class="modal fade" id="yelpModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="yelpModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content" style="background-color: #fafafa">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="yelpModalLabel">Add a Business</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <script src="../static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
            <script src="../static/js/ajax.js"></script>

            <h3>Add a place from Yelp</h3>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <!--Change value of yelpIsLocation to determine type of search-->
                <button type="button" id="yelpIsNear" class="active btn btn-default" name="inputAddress" value="yes" onclick="document.getElementById('yelpIsLocation').value='no';returnUserPosition();">Search near you</button>
                <button type="button" id="yelpIsLocation" class="btn btn-default" name="inputAddress" value="no" onclick="this.value='yes';enableLocationSearch();">Search for address</button><br>
            </div>

            <div id="userCoord" style="display:block;">
                <p><small id="placeholderWhileGettingLocation"></small></p>
                <p><span id="userLat" style="display:none;"></span>
                <span id="userLong" style="display:none;"></span></p>
            </div>

            <form id="ajaxForm">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <!--User provided location-->
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 col-xs-12">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E.g. 200 California St" id="ajaxLocation"><br>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E.g. dinner" id="ajaxTerm">
                </div>
                <!--Coordinates stay hidden-->
                <input id="yelpGeoCoordLat" type="text" style="display:inline-block;visibility:hidden;">
                <input id="yelpGeoCoordLong" type="text" style="display:inline-block;visibility:hidden;">
            </form>
            <br>
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="yelp_ajax();">Search on Yelp!</button>&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addPlaceModal">Add Manually</button>
            </div>
            <p></p>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div id="yelpOutput"></div>

            <script src="../static/js/yelp_search.js"></script>

        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#newModal">Done</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is same issue in this link([bootstrap modal issue in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114009/bootstrap-modal-issue-in-chrome/29331719#29331719))

I found it today, so there is my answer about it.

I copied and pasted it below...

---

I got the same problem. I found the solution, but I don't know How It Works. The solution is, add some jquery codes I wrote below.

```
$('.modal').bind('shown.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".modal").css("overflow-y", "scroll");
});
$('.modal').bind('hide.bs.modal', function () {
  $(".modal").css("overflow-y", "auto");
});
```

Good Luck!